# Express route handle for admin and admin/* with same routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My all admin/whatever url is rendering admin file but when i try to hit just admin it show 404 not go in this route. I can create separate route for just url/admin but is their any other option. So that i could manage only by single route .

```
  app.get('/admin/*', function (req, res, next) {
       res.render('admin');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `/` after `admin` so it can match the route

```
app.get('/admin*', function (req, res, next) {
       res.render('admin');
  });
```